# wishlist and commerce bundle

Tags: views, commerce, flags

i have [commerce_bundle](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bundle) module installed, and we use it to implement (shop the look) concept, the problem is that we already use flags to implement wishlist for separate products and view the items added to wishlist by a view, now we need to allow bundles to be added to wishlist, but we can't view it in the same view that render the products items in wishlist. are there any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: the fields we use for the wishlist view are:-

(Products referenced by field_product) Commerce Product: Product Images
Content: Title (Title)

(Products referenced by field_product) Commerce Product: Price (Price)

(flag) Flags: Flag link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this sandbox](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/nvahalik/2659242) which reimplements Wishlists as orders. It won't work out of the box since it only hooks into the main add to cart form, so you'd need to add that in... but it's an order so you can theme it like a regular cart/order form.